# How to save a web table into a resultset variable?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am trying to fetch the data from table . How to save a web table into a result set variable using pace automation framework ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table rowXpath="//table/tbody/tr" resultsetVar="web_table" primaryKey="User ID"  colNames="User Name,User ID,User Email,Assigned Study,Study Role">

<tableData colName="User Name" xpath="./td[1]" type="text"></tableData> 
<tableData colName="User ID" xpath="./td[2]" type="text"></tableData>
<tableData colName="User Email" xpath="./td[3]" type="text"></tableData> 
<tableData colName="Assigned Study" xpath="./td[4]" type="text"></tableData> 
<tableData colName="Study Role" xpath="./td[5]" type="text"></tableData>

</table>
```